# What haven't done right here?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, http-status-code-404

I have been stalk here for weeks, try every possible I could lay my hands on all to no expected result. I want to display the details of book when a user search and click on the book link. I have the search route working properly but the book route that is supposed to render the book details is giving me a 404 Not Found error. with this; The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Pls I need someone to look at this code for me and tell me want I have done wrong and how I can get it working.

Here is the code.

```
@app.route("/book/<isbn>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@loggedin_required
def book(isbn):
    """ Takes and renders user review on the book page."""

    if request.method == "POST":

        # Keep track of individual user per session
        active_user = session["user_id"]
        
        # Fetch data from form
        rating = request.form.get("rating")
        comment = request.form.get("comment")
        
        # Get book_id by ISBN
        row = db.execute("SELECT id FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn",
                        {"isbn": isbn})

        # Saving id into variable
        _id = row.fetchone() # (id,)
        _Id = _id[0]

        # Check to ensure that its ONLY 1 review/user per book)
        row_check = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE user_id = :user_id AND book_id = :book_id",
                    {"user_id": active_user,
                     "book_id": _id})

        if row_check.rowcount > 0:
            
            flash('You have left a review for this book already.')
            return redirect("/book/" + isbn)

        # Convert to save into DB
        rating_result = int(rating_result)

        db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (user_id, book_id, comments, rating_result) VALUES \
                    (:user_id, :book_id, :comments, :rating_result)",
                    {"user_id": active_user, 
                    "book_id": _id, 
                    "comments": comment, 
                    "rating_result": rating})

       
        db.commit()

        flash('Review recieved. Thank you!')

        return redirect("/book/" + isbn)
    
    # Take the book ISBN and redirect to his page (GET)
    else:

        row = db.execute("SELECT isbn, title, author, year FROM books WHERE \
                        isbn = :isbn",
                        {"isbn": isbn})

        book_details = row.fetchall()
        
        return render_template("/book.html", isbn=isbn, book_details=book_details)
```

This is the search method:

```
@app.route("/search")
@loggedin_required
def search():
    
    """ check if book id is supply"""
    if not request.args.get("book"):
        return render_template("error.html", message="Sorry! you didn't supply a book")
    
    query = "%" + request.args.get("book") + "%"
    
    query = query.title()
    rows = db.execute("SELECT isbn, title, author FROM books WHERE \
                        isbn LIKE :query OR \
                        title LIKE :query OR \
                        author LIKE :query LIMIT 20", 
                        {"query":query})
    
    if rows.rowcount == 0:
        return render_template("error.html", message="No book matches your search")
    
    books = rows.fetchall()
    
    return render_template("search.html", books=books)
```

And this is the html page that is processed and render by the the search function:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
search
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    
        {% for book in books %}
        <a href="{{url_for('book', isbn=isbn)}}" class="card-link">
                 {{book.title}} by {{book.author}} 
                </a>
                
        {% endfor %}
            
</div>
```

The herf link is supposed to be process by the book route but when clicked on the link after search, it throughs the 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Add the URL that is being used when the user clicks on the link to your question.

Comment: If this is the code that isn't getting run, changes are very good that your problem is elsewhere. Can you show us the route definition and signature of the search method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template, i guess you should pass `book.isbn` as a parameter for `book` url and not `isbn`, because you are looping on `books` and it's not defined elsewhere so it will be passed as `None` and thus you will get 404 Not Found.

```
[..]
        {% for book in books %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('book', isbn=book.isbn) }}" class="card-link">
          {{book.title}} by {{book.author}} 
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
[..]
```